# Prove that the limit of $\frac{xy}{|y|}$ at (0,0) does not exist

Tags: limits

How to prove that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{|y|}$$ doesn't exist? I tried to prove it with paths but it's not working. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Title and question are different. Which one of them is your question?

Comment: lim xy/|y| as (x,y)→(0,0)

Comment: wolfram says is doesnt exist

Comment: Who/what do you trust more? :-)

Comment: ok , so the limit of:
(x^3*k)/((x^2+|k|)*(sqrt(x^2+y^2))) as x->0,k->0 , is 0?

Answer (score 3):

It exists:$$\left|\frac{xy}{|y|}\right|=|x|\to 0$$